# iOS8 custom keyboard accessing user defaults without requesting open access

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios8, nsuserdefaults

I'm implementing a custom keyboard for iOS8. I have a containing app that sets a few keyboard specific values to `NSUserDefaults` so that the keyboard can read from them.

This works fine, however I **must** set `requestsOpenAccess` to yes to get this working on device.

This seems like overkill to me, I only want to read a few values from the containing app. I don't want any of the other features of the networked keyboard.

Does any one know if there is a way to read values set in the containing app without requesting open access?

Comment: Try writing to a custom `plist` file.

Comment: Doesn't file sharing between the keyboard and the containing app also need open access?

Comment: not sure, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to share  content between host app and keyboard extension without `requestOpenAccess`.

You have to enabled a shared container for host app and keyboard extension, and use

> [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:];

to access a shared NSUserDefaults.

Yes it is overkill, but this is the only way.